# Как изменить свойство контекста из c++?

Tags: c++, qt5, qml

Вопрос такой, как я могу изменить свойство контекста, которое было задано как

```
_core->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("currentZoneProperty", new CurrentZoneProperty);
```

Где CurrentZoneProperty следующий класс

```
class CurrentZoneProperty final : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(QString currentName READ currentName WRITE setCurrentName NOTIFY currentNameChanged)

public:
QString currentName() noexcept;
void setCurrentName(const QString &currentName) noexcept;

Q_SIGNAL void currentNameChanged();

private:
QString _currentName;
};
```

Как я могу из другой части кода c++ могу обратиться к текущему свойству и изменить его свойство currentName? Из части qml это понятно, я там сразу вызываю обработку, но мне нужно именно прям из другой части c++...

Comment: Сохраните указатель на созданный объект и вызывайте нужные функции-члены. В крайнем случае, можете получить QVariant с помощью contextProperty

Comment: @Croessmah, Да, в принципе это рациональный подход, спасибо за идею. Можете бахнуть это в ответ, я галку Вам поставлю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете сохранить указатель на передаваемый в QML объект, и вызывать его функции-члены непосредственно из C++.
Также Вы можете запросить свойство с помощью `contextProperty` и получить `QVariant` с нужным Вам свойством.

Не забывайте, что установка свойства через `setContextProperty` **не передает владение** объектом в QML. Это значит, что в Вашем случае созданный динамический объект типа `CurrentZoneProperty` в результате никто не удалит, если Вы сами об этом не позаботитесь.